# how to send and receive response from Websocket Connection using robot framework

Tags: websocket, automation, robotframework

I have to validate the WebSocket data with ui. We used URL: WSS://******/websocket and have to send request for connection as:  ["{\"msg\":\"connect\",\"version\":\"1\",\"support\":[\"1\",\"pre2\",\"pre1\"]}"]

I followed this one 
[image]

${my_websocket1} I got the response as integer values

Comment: What's your question then? Please format your message and include what you have tried already.

Comment: How to send and receive Json response using robot framework for automation?